# Folder deleting after script ends

Tags: windows, powershell

I am currently writing a script that takes a folder of files, moves the first file to a folder with a specific name, then move the rest to another folder with a number for a name.

My script works however it also moves the folder and renames it too. Which section of the code is causing this?

```
$path = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MergeTest\_First\"

$FileCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
$FirstFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -File | Select-Object -First 1

$FinalReport = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MergeTest\___Final\TestOutput.xlsx"

Move-Item "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MergeTest\_First\$FirstFile" $FinalReport

$Counter = 0;



Write-host $FileCount





for($Counter = 0; $Counter -lt $FileCount; $Counter++)
{


$FileInWork = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -File | Select-Object -First 1

move-item "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MergeTest\_First\$FileInWork" "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MergeTest\__Second\$Counter.xlsx"
Write-host "File Moved"

}
```

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: I fixed the issue, however i cannot remember the exact solution!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is specify the `-Include *.txt` condition to your move-item commands so it is only to move just .txt, .log, or whatever file type you're moving and leave the folder how it is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code could do with some cleaning up. Now you are executing `Get-ChildItem` 3 times, where using it once is enough.

Also, you should try and use the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) rather than constructing the path and filenames yourself.
Especially where you do `"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MergeTest\_First\$FileInWork"`, you should realize that `Get-ChildItem` returns FileInfo and/or DirectoryInfo **objects**; not strings.

Anyway, the below code should do what you want:

```
# define the path where all other paths are in
$rootPath          = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MergeTest"
# create the working paths using the common root folder path
$filesPath         = Join-Path -Path $rootPath -ChildPath '_First'
$firstDestination  = Join-Path -Path $rootPath -ChildPath '___Final'
$secondDestination = Join-Path -Path $rootPath -ChildPath '__Second'

# test if the destination folders exist and if not create them
if (!(Test-Path -Path $firstDestination -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Host "Creating folder '$firstDestination'"
    $null = New-Item -Path $firstDestination -ItemType Directory
}
if (!(Test-Path -Path $secondDestination -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Host "Creating folder '$secondDestination'"
    $null = New-Item -Path $secondDestination -ItemType Directory
}

# get an array of all FileInfo objects in $filesPath
# you could consider adding -Filter '*.xlsx' here..
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesPath -Force -File

Write-Host 'Total number of files found: {0}' -f $allFiles.Count

# move the files
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $allFiles.Count; $i++) {
    if ($i -eq 0) {
        # the first file should go in the $firstDestination folder with specified name
        $target = Join-Path -Path $firstDestination -ChildPath 'TestOutput.xlsx'
    }
    else {
        # all other files go to the $secondDestination folder
        # each file should have the index number as name
        $target = Join-Path -Path $secondDestination -ChildPath ('{0}.xlsx' -f ($i + 1))
    }
    $allFiles[$i] | Move-Item -Destination $target -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Hope that helps

Remove the `-WhatIf` if you are satisfied with whatever the output on console shows.

P.S. I really think you should edit your question and change its title, because nothing in the question has to do with *Folder deleting after script ends*..